# Is (x,0) the only solution?

Tags: number-theory

I am given the exercise:" For which $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ has the diophantine equation $x^2-y^2=n$ a solution? "

My question is..if $n$ is a square,then is $(x,0)$ the only solution or is it also possible that there is a solution with $x \neq 0$ and also $y \neq 0$(at the case that $n$ is a square) ?

Comment: Nothing in the problem seems to ask for $n$ to be a square.

Comment: I saw the solution in my notes and there they take this case..

Comment: But the problem itself is asking which numbers are difference of two squares, right?

Comment: Yes..so,you mean that the difference of two squares,that are both different from $0$ , cannot be equal to an other square?

Comment: Sorry, I was on a plane for a few hours. As you have stated the problem, the “square” issue is beside the point. Clear your mind of cases when $n$ is a square and answer the question fully: which numbers are the difference of two squares? If you’re having difficulty with this, write down a list of the ten first squares, and see which numbers are the difference of two things on your list. I keep harping on this, I know, but knowledge proceeds from examples. Your problem is that you haven’t been thinking of examples. (AND MAKE SURE YOUR LIST OF SQUARES INCLUDES ZERO.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite the equation as:
$$(x+y)(x-y)=n$$
We can find a solution if:
$$x+y=n, x-y =1 \Rightarrow 2x=n+1, 2y=n-1$$
This works for any odd $n$.

So suppose $n$ is even, that is, $n=2k$.
Then we have 
$$(x+y)(x-y)=2k$$
We can find a solution if:
$$x+y=k, x-y=2 \Rightarrow 2x=k+2, 2y=k-2$$
This works for any even $k$, meaning for any $n$ that is a multiple of 4.

That leaves the question if we can find a solution for $n=4\ell+2$...

Comment: I understand..Thank you very much!!! So,the case that $n$ is a square and $x,y \neq 0$, is included at the solutions you found above,right?

Comment: Hmm. Not really. It appears I misunderstood your question. It seems you want to find solutions for $x^2-y^2=z^2$. That can be rewritten as $y^2+z^2=x^2$, which has an infinite number of solutions - the so called Pythagorean triples. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple to generate solutions.

Comment: I am looking again at the exercise..At the case when $n$ is odd, is $d=n,e=1$ the only solution,or could the equation have also other ones?

Comment: What are $d$ and $e$? With $n$ odd there is one solution: $x=\frac{n+1}{2}, y=\frac{n-1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Pythagorean Theorem. Also, take a look at the differences between squares.

Comment: My basic question is the case at which $n$ is a square..Is it possible then that the diophantine equation has an other solution,except from this one: $(x,0)$ ?

Comment: If $n$ is a square, is there a solution to $x^2 = n + y^2$? Try $n = 4$, for example.

Comment: Maybe you mean, $n=4^2$.

Comment: @ChristopherLiu So is it not possible that the difference of two non-zero squares is equal to an other square??

Comment: $3^2+4^2=\dots?$, evinda.